# Login form validation is working but other forms validation is not working

Tags: magento2, validation

I have tried all types of method but only login form validation is applying. But other forms not working. Even writing js in the phtml is not applying for the other forms.

```
<form class="form form-edit-account" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('customer/account/editPost')) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>" autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'">
<fieldset class="fieldset info">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Account Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getCustomer())->toHtml() ?>

    <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
    <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
    <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getCustomer()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getCustomer()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_gender->setGender($block->getCustomer()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <div class="field choice">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change_email" id="change-email" data-role="change-email" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Change Email')) ?>" class="checkbox" />
        <label class="label" for="change-email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="field choice">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change-password" data-role="change-password" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Change Password')) ?>"<?php if ($block->getChangePassword()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
        <label class="label" for="change-password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="fieldset password" data-container="change-email-password">
    <legend class="legend"><span data-title="change-email-password"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email and Password')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <div class="field email required" data-container="change-email">
        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="email" data-input="change-email" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{'required':true,'validate-length':true,'minlength':6,'maxlength':50,'validate-email':true}" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field password current required">
        <label class="label" for="current-password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Current Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="current_password" id="current-password" data-input="current-password" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field new password required" data-container="new-password">
        <label class="label" for="password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('New Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="password"
                data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                data-input="new-password"
                data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                autocomplete="off" />
            <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                    <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field confirm password required" data-container="confirm-password">
        <label class="label" for="password-confirmation"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm New Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_confirmation" id="password-confirmation"
                data-input="confirm-password"
                autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit" class="action save primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Save')) ?></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage"
    ], function($){
        var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
        var ignore = isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null' ?>;

        dataForm.mage('validation', {
        isEnabled()): ?>
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                    var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                        errorClass = error.prop('class');
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                        .after('');
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
        
            ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
        
        });

    });



    {
        "[data-role=change-email], [data-role=change-password]": {
            "changeEmailPassword": {
                "titleChangeEmail": "escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email'))) ?>",
                "titleChangePassword": "escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password'))) ?>",
                "titleChangeEmailAndPassword": "escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email and Password'))) ?>"
            }
        },
        "[data-container=new-password]": {
            "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
                "formSelector": "form.form-edit-account"
            }
        }
    }

Comment: data-validate="{'required':true,'validate-length':true,'validate-number':true,'minlength':6,'maxlength':50}" the above code is not applying

Comment: data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' I have also used the above code in the form

Comment: I am also not getting the error message

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also post the full form code to your question.